# Proof of $ x = \mu + \epsilon $ for a random $x$ from population $N(\mu, \sigma)$

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable

Let's say $x$ is a random variable drawn from a normally distributed population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then we can write $x$ in terms of $\mu$ and a random error component $\epsilon$ as:
$$
x = \mu + \epsilon
$$

Can someone explain (or point me to some resources) which proves this.

More specifically, what does the noise term $\epsilon$ consist of, and is it related somehow to the variance $\sigma^2$ of the distribution?

Comment: Hi,

It seems this question received a few down votes. Can I have some specific reason, why is it so? (Lack of effort, too simple question to ask, or something else maybe)

So that from future I can take care of it in a better way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that noise is normally distributed with zero mean $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, then you take $X = \varepsilon + \mu$ and since $E(Y+c) = E(Y) + c$ (where $Y$ is a random variable and $c$ is a constant) the new mean is $\mu$ rather then $0$.

Comment: Yeah. it seems so simple now that you have framed in in such a lucid way. Thank you.